# Passing Arguments to Running Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, runtime

I have a bash script that takes a list of IP Addresses, and pings them every 15 seconds to test connectivity. Some of these IP Addresses are servers and computers as to which I have the ability to control. I would like to be able to do something of the following:

- Run The Bash File
- It pings non-controlled IP Addresses
- It will list the controlled Computers
- When a computer turns off, it sends my script a response saying it turned off
- The script outputs accordingly

I have the code all set up that pings these computers every 15 seconds and displays. What I wish to achieve is to **NOT** ping my controlled computers. They will send a command to the bash script. I know this can be done by writing a file and reading such file, but I would like a way that changes the display **AS IT HAPPENS**. Would `mkfifo` be an viable option?

Comment: For Example. IP 1.1.1.1 shuts down, it sends my computer the command necessary, and the script updates then and there. Regardless of the 15 seconds countdown.

Comment: Why can't the script react to the command and remove the IP from whatever list it was using ?

Comment: The list is never shortened. It just prints online, and offline. When a computer goes offline, I would like it to update immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `mkfifo` is ok for this task. For instance, this:

```
mkfifo ./commandlist

while read f < ./commandlist; do
    # Actions here
    echo $f
done
```

will wait until a new line can be read from FIFO `commandlist`, read it into `$f` and execute the body.

From the outside, write to the FIFO with:

```
echo 42 > ./commandlist
```

**But**, why not let the remote server call this script, perhaps via SSH or even CGI? You can setup a `/notify-disconnect` CGI script with no parameters and get the IP address of the peer from the `REMOTE_ADDR` environment variable.

Comment: My computer has 2 monitors. My main usage monitor, and my statistics monitor. On the statistics monitor, I have online/offline IP Addresses refreshing every 15 seconds. With this set up, I do not see how the remote server could use CGI. SSH would allow the opportunity for writing to the `mkfifo` file, however, I would have to add some logic into the statistics script to allow for the setup you have provided.